# Python subprocess produced output or not

Tags: python, communication, subprocess

This question is in relation to:

[python, subprocess: reading output from subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804727/python-subprocess-reading-output-from-subprocess)

If P is a subprocess started with a command along the lines of

```
import subprocess

P = subprocess.Popen ("command", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

we can read the output P produces by P.stdout.readline ().  This is a blocking read though.  How can I check if there is output ready for reading (without blocking)?

Comment: Following on SO: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-stream-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-blocking read on a stream in python.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-stream-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *nix, then you can use the [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) module to poll the stdout file descriptor

```
import subprocess
import select
poller = select.epoll()

P = subprocess.Popen ("command", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
poller.register(P.stdout, select.EPOLLHUP)

while True:
    #block indefinitely: timeout = -1
    #return immediately: timeout = 0
    for fd, flags in poller.poll(timeout=0)
        foo = P.stdout.readline()
    #do something else before the next poll
```