# How to Use Python Subprocess to Write a String to a File

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to figure out what happens in `subprocess`.
So, I write this code:

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen('grep a', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('grep a', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=open('test', 'w'),shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

p1.stdin.write("asdads"*700)
```

After I write the string to `p1.stdin`, I expected the string to be written to the file `test`.
But there is nothing in the file.

When I tried another way:

```
out, err = p1.communicate("adsad"*700)
```

The string is in `out`.

Comment: Why not use `open` to open a file and write it the normal way?

Comment: I am trying to learn how subprocess works

Comment: Maybe start with a simpler problem, like calling a command like `ls` or `date` and seeing it's output?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I tried that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code wasn't working because your `stdin` stream is not closed. To prove what I'm saying:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('grep l', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
out, err = p1.communicate('hello')

>>> out
'hello\n'
```

Now test with `communicate`, which automatically closes stream for you.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('grep l', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('grep h', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=open('test', 'w'),shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

# test is already created and empty
# but call communicate again can write to file
>>> p1.communicate('hello')
('', None)

$cat test
hello
```

And another way:

```
# use stdin.write
>>> p1.stdin.write('hello') # empty file
>>> p1.stdin.close() # flushed
```

References:

1. [subprocess popen.communicate() vs. stdin.write() and stdout.read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141712/subprocess-popen-communicate-vs-stdin-write-and-stdout-read)
2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate