# What's the difference between `bufsize` parameter values in Python3's Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` to run different scripts from another python script and some of them just hang in some point until they are killed by the scheduler script. I tried setting `bufsize` to `100 * 1024 * 1024` but didn't succeeded solving the problem. If I ignore all the output setting `stdout`and `stderr` to `subprocess.DEVNULL` it doesn't get stuck.

Example:

```
# For most scripts this works, but for long running and very verbose scripts, it gets stuck
subprocess.Popen(args=args_list, bufsize=100*1024*1024, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

# This works fine, but I don't get the stderr content
subprocess.Popen(args=args_list, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you actually communicate with the subprocess, e.g. by reading stdout/stderr or using ``.communicate``?

Comment: Yes! After a while I call `.communicate()` and select the second element from the returned list. I just need this so I can send an alarm in case of failure with the error to the script maintainer

Answer (score 0):

#### Large buffers should only be configured for performance, and never relied on as a correctness measure.

That means that using a large `bufsize` is not a suitable replacement for ensuring that you can handle reading from a subprocess's stdout and stderr in whichever order contents become available. An operating system isn't guaranteed to support arbitrarily-sized I/O buffers; you should never assume that just because you *request* a buffer of a given size, you're going to actually receive it.

On Linux, for example, *some* kernel versions support the `F_SETPIPE_SZ` ioctl to request a given pipe buffer size. However, unprivileged processes can't actually set to this to any value larger than the `fs.pipe-max-size` sysctl, *so this request may fail*; your program needs to be prepared for such a failure.

---

#### Thus, use the general best-practices for reading from a subprocess, no matter what your buffer size is.

That means, in something like a rough order of preference:

- Using `subprocess.communicate()` wherever you can.
- Combining stdout and stderr into a single file descriptor, if you don't actually need to care about the distinction between them.
- Reading from both descriptors, either asynchronously or simultaneously through threading, to ensure that writes that happen will be handled in the order they came in.

As some existing Q&A entries that will help, see:

- [Python read from subprocess stdout and stderr separately while preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833897/python-read-from-subprocess-stdout-and-stderr-separately-while-preserving-order)
- [subprocess popen.communicate() vs. stdin.write() and stdout.read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141712/subprocess-popen-communicate-vs-stdin-write-and-stdout-read)