# Get output of active python script - Windows OS

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, cmd

I have 10 python windows that are running a code.
Every script has specific word in output (running instance1, running instance2,running instance3..)...

sometimes script crashes and [try: except:] method doesn't work on this.

So I need a way to loop trough open python windows and ask: 
does the any of python windows contain in their output word 'running instance1', or 'running instance2' and if it doesn't then 'do this'...

EDIT:
Popen and subprocess can be used when you are calling a .py from another .py. I need something to read output of already running .py program.  I need a way to connect to its output window over PID or name like python.exe.

Anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python, subprocess: reading output from subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804727/python-subprocess-reading-output-from-subprocess)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the exception handling [try: except:] and not have another layer to make up for it?